# Append textbox only once

Tags: javascript, html

i have a checkbox with function to append a textbox onclick..now issue is each time i click the checkbox a new textbox appears and if i click the checkbox say 10 times i get 10 textboxes..i want to stop that and i cant use the disabling textbox once clicked as there is a function that doesnt work properly when disabling the textbox. Any help on this will be appreciated.

```
<input onClick="myFunction();" id="demoteTask" name="demoteTask" type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;<label for"demoteTask_cbx">Demote to Child</label>

<span id="DemoteContainer"></span>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
}
</script>
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<script>
var tmp=1;
function myFunction() {
if(tmp%2==1)
{
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
tmp++;
}
else
{
var d = document.getElementById("DemoteContainer");
var d_nested = document.getElementById("parent");
var throwawayNode = d.removeChild(d_nested);
tmp++;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<input onClick="myFunction();" id="demoteTask" name="demoteTask" type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;<label for"demoteTask_cbx">Demote to Child</label>

<span id="DemoteContainer"></span>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById('demoteTask');
  if (!checkBox.checked) {
    document.getElementById("parent").remove()
  } else {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
    document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
  }
}
  
  
  
</script>
```

Comment: i dont want my checkbox to be disabled since other functions depend on its value

Answer (score 3):

you could check if the element(text box) exists prior to adding the text box, as:

```
function myFunction() {
    //check if text box with id "parent" exists, add if doesn't
    if( !document.getElementById("parent") ) {
        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        span.innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
        document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
    }
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
    //check if text box with id "parent" exists, add if doesn't
    if( !document.querySelector("#DemoteContainer input#parent") ) {
        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        span.innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
        document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
    }
}
```

Comment: i also want to remove it on 2nd click if the textbox exists

Answer (score 2):

Replace the script with the following one:-

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("parent");
    if(elem != null)
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").appendChild(span);
// document.getElementById("demoteTask").disabled = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i also want to remove it on 2nd click if the textbox exists

Comment: What do you want to remove?

Comment: say if the user doesnt want to tick the checkbox and does it by mistake and now he wants to remove it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having textbox generated again each time it's clicked, use innerHTML to replace the whole content of container, instead of appendChild:

```js
document.getElementById("DemoteContainer").innerHTML = '<input id="parent" name = "parent" type="textbox" />';
```

Comment: i dont want it to generate each time on click.. that is the issue i am facing now..